# How to store a file as a string in a model text field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am pretty new to Django. I need some help.

I am working on an admin page that allows me to edit objects. My model has a text field that I want to fill with a file contents which will be uploaded with a FileInput widget in a form.

So I want to read the file contents, put it in a string and store it in the model text field. Therefore it should be saved in the database.

Any help with this? I dont know how to get the file , read it and store it in my model as string. I am using a ModelAdmin btw.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you might want to just use a `model.FileField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield). The database only has to store a path to the file, instead of the entire contents of the file. You might not want to store the contents of a file directly in the database, especially if its a large file.

But if you do want to read a file in to your model. Try something along the lines of:

models.py

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    textfield = TextField()
```

views.py or whatever script you are calling

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
newmodel = SomeModel()
newmodel.textfield = data
newmodel.save()
```

Comment: I am using a ModelForm and a FileInput. I am trying to receive the file in the clean method of the field but I only receive the file name, not the file itself so I can't read the file contents. I am replacing the field widget (which is a TextField) with a FileInput.

Comment: Again I think your best case scenario is to use FileField, and you can still use the FileInput widget with it. That way you don't have to worry about reading the file in at that moment. You can then later access the model's field and it is treated like a normal file object.

Comment: And How could I provide a link to download the file in the form? It's an admin form so I have no access to html

Comment: Why do you need to provide a link to download the file in the form? Aren't you trying to upload the file in the form? I guess explaining your use case here might help a little more.

Comment: Yea, but that file needs to be modified so I need to be able to download it to edit it after.

Comment: So after you upload the file to the model (lets say the field is called `filefield`), you can reference the model field using the `url` attribute of the file field. For example `model_instance.filefield.url`. Let me know if you need explanation for how to do that in more detail.

Comment: Basically, you upload the file to the model, save the model instance, and then later you can grab the model instance and get the file's link using the `url` parameter of the FileField

Comment: The problem is I am not literally saving or accessing the model to show because I am working on the admin page. I am just calling `admin.site.register`.